Trying to import latex2sympy2 and ERROR "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'typing.io'; 'typing' is not a package"
I followed step by step installation for the Latex Sympy Calculator from this page : https://github.com/OrangeX4/Latex-Sympy-Calculator/blob/main/README.md
But when trying, on VS Code, import latex2sympy2 I get :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<python-input-1>", line 1, in <module>
    import latex2sympy2
  File "C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\latex2sympy2.py", line 4, in <module>
    from antlr4 import InputStream, CommonTokenStream
  File "C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\antlr4\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from antlr4.CommonTokenStream import CommonTokenStream
  File "C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\antlr4\CommonTokenStream.py", line 33, in <module>
    from antlr4.Lexer import Lexer
  File "C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\antlr4\Lexer.py", line 12, in <module>
    from typing.io import TextIO
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'typing.io'; 'typing' is not a package

I'm with Python 3.13.0 installed.
I tried uninstalling all versions of python and install back and nothing changed.
Note that I did exactly the same on another computer (both on Windows 11) and it works perfectly on the other one but not on this one.

You need python 3.12 or below for this to work - typing.io was deprecated long ago and removed in 3.13. Another computer likely runs python 3.12 or below - 3.13 was only released in this October.

That worked. I may have the 3.13 installed on my other computer. Thanks.

Please do not edit the question to include the solution; post a self-answer instead.

The latest version of antlr4-python3-runtime does not have the problematic code. You appear to be using an outdated version.

@STerliakov Please convert the comment to an answer.

I installed the Latex Sympy Calculator vscode extension from here.
Once you start using python 3.12 you may run into the following problem: the server won't start.
You can work around this problem by starting it manually. Run the following "latex_sympy_cal_start_server.py" code.
import subprocess

subprocess.run([ 'python',
                  r'C:\Users\charl\.vscode\extensions\orangex4.latex-sympy-calculator-1.6.0\server.py'
               ]) #          ^
                  #          |      
                  #          +--- use your own user name here

Once the server is running the calculator will work.
Put the extension's examples in an .md file if you have not done so already. If you don't already have a preview window (the right hand window in the Latex Sympy Calculator extension's examples) click into the .md file and use "CTRL-k v" to open it.

When I do that I get the same error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'typing.io'; 'typing' is not a package. In the server.py file, there is a import latex2sympy2 so it lead to the same problem.

Please use the "Python" extension of VScode. Select the "Python" extension and then under "WORKSPACE ENVIRONMENTS", examine the one with the star next to its name. This is the environment that it used when you run code in vscode. Under this environment, expose the list of "Packages". I'll bet that latex2sympy2 isn't in the list. Of course, Flask also needs to be in that list.  You can install new packages by clicking on the magnifying glass icon. You can also switch to any other of the environments, including any of the "GLOBAL" ones, by hovering over the name and clicking on the star.

From the comment section:

You need python 3.12 or below for this to work - typing.io was deprecated long ago and removed in 3.13. Another computer likely runs python 3.12 or below - 3.13 was only released in this October.
— @STerliakov, Oct 19 at 0:35

